# Populating Columns headings from JSON in bootstrap-table?

Tags: jquery, json, bootstrap-table

I can how to populate the data from the JSON file on my server (url: file.json), but then I still need to declare the columns themselves manually as I initiate the bootstrap table.

I would like to populate the entire table according to the JSON information. Is the possible?

Current code:

```
function create_table_from_json() {
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
        url: 'data.json',
        columns: [{
            field: 'firstname',
            title: 'First Name',
            sortable: 'true'

            }, {
            field: 'lastname',
            title: 'Last Name',
            sortable: 'true'
            }, {
            field: 'desc',
            title: 'Description'
            }, {
            field: 'donotcall',
            title: 'Do Not Call'
            }],

        sortName:   'lastname',
        striped:    'true',
        search:     'true',
        showColumns: 'true'

    });
}
```

*sidenote:

If anyone has experience with other table enhancement tools or plugins and wants to recommend them that would be great.*

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Hey yeah I was able to write a column-builder function that used the data from the json in order to build the columns with various attribute and everything. I'll post it later.

Comment: Since then I have worked with the DEV, there was a bug and you can now set columns with JSON. Might be the answer, might just be helpful for later. The change has to be fixed in the JS as it is not available on the DEV pr PROD CDN. This post in full has all the details. https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/3895

Comment: Hey i took a look at my code. I basically just took the JSON and made a function `buildColumns(json)` which iterates through the JSON object and defines a JSON object for each column which is then pushed to the columns array. I end up returning the columns array and in the definition of the table i just inject that into the columns option.

Answer (score 2):

Long story short will be in the next release as fix.

Confirmed it seems to be accepting the JSON via JS and populating the columns and data properly now.

Primitive example in case someone stumbles on this. Keep in mind the JSON has values needed for the column filter control which you might not need.

```
$table.bootstrapTable({
    height: getHeight(),
    data: fromAJAXJSON.data,
    columns: fromAJAXJSON.columns
});
```

In a perfect world you would most likely want to combine the data and columns into one JSON call for timing reasons rootObject.data/rootObject.columns but you get the point.
Example data JSON: https://api.myjson.com/bins/r8nya
Example columns JSON: https://api.myjson.com/bins/zkqf6

https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/3895